# How to create summary in list and create total in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The code below is working but I need help in summarizing and sorting the output to create a more readable output.

```
account = []
amount = []

pmtReceived = []
for payment in payments_received: 
    print ("  ({:>15}) <-  {}".format(payment['amount'] ,payment['from']))
    pmtReceived.append(payment['amount'])

    account.append(payment['to'])
    amount.append(payment['amount'])

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2)), columns =['To', 'Amount'])

print (df)
```

Current Output:

```
       Account      Amount       
0  BD001ABC... 180.0000000 
1  ACC011XY... 120.0000000
2  ACC011XY... 444.0000000  
3  012ABC1A... 190.0000000
4  012ABC1A...  50.0000000
5  012ABC1A... 110.0000000
6  012ABC1A... 400.0000000  
7  XY123AYT...   0.4900000
```

Needed Output:

```
BD001ABC (1 Transaction / 180.0)
ACC011XY (2 Transaction / 564.0)
012ABC1A (4 Transaction / 750.0)
XY123AYT (1 Transaction / 0.49)
```

Comment: Do you know Panda? You can create a Dataframe from your dict/list and then do some groupby, aggregation, sort,... with it. Dataframe is just like a table with rows and columns, it's easy to read, so if your goal is just "Readable" then it's a good idea.

Comment: I think you are just looking for a groupby with an aggregate method that can be used to pass multiple aggregations at once. Here is a [tutorial/blog](http://akshaysehgal.com/blog/groupby.html) that should be an end to end guide on how you can use group and aggregate. Disclaimer, the author of this blog is me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Add this to your current function and return `result`

```
result = df.groupby('Account')['Amount'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()
result['count'] = result['count'].astype(str) + ' Transactions'
print(result)
```

```
       Account           count     sum
0  012ABC1A...  4 Transactions  750.00
1  ACC011XY...  2 Transactions  564.00
2  BD001ABC...  1 Transactions  180.00
3  XY123AYT...  1 Transactions    0.49
```

---

If you want to also display the list of all the transactions, then you can add one more aggregation method to the `.agg()` -

```
df.groupby('Account')['Amount'].agg([list,'count','sum']).reset_index()
```

```
       Account                         list  count     sum
0  012ABC1A...  [190.0, 50.0, 110.0, 400.0]      4  750.00
1  ACC011XY...               [120.0, 444.0]      2  564.00
2  BD001ABC...                      [180.0]      1  180.00
3  XY123AYT...                       [0.49]      1    0.49
```

---

#### References for further reading

Here is the [official documentation on pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and here is a [blog / tutorial](http://akshaysehgal.com/blog/groupby.html) that should be an end-to-end guide for how to use groupby in pandas. Disclaimer, the author of the blog is me.

Comment: Thank you. My codes here seems off. Can you show your complete code? TIA

Comment: after you are creating the variable df, just use the 2 lines of code in my answer. that is my complete code.

Comment: I cant to make the sum works: `012ABC1A...  5 Transactions  100.000000050.0000000300.0000000300.0000000250...`

Comment: great tutorial, thanks a lot

Comment: @SergFSM glad you like it! @ errzoned, do edit your question with this case, its difficult to see what is failing in the comment. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

`payments_received.sort()`

then run your loop. if you need descending order try `payments_received.sort(reverse=True)`

cheers